# How do I know if the GMP library is installed in my machine

Tags: gmp

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and I am trying to figure out if I have installed the GMP library.

I have tried `locate libgmp.a`, but nothing shows up. But if I run `locate libgmp.so` I get the following output:

```
/snap/code/107/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/code/107/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
/snap/code/108/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/code/108/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
/snap/core/13425/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/core/13425/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
/snap/core/13425/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgmp.so
/snap/core/13741/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/core/13741/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.0
/snap/core/13741/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgmp.so
/snap/core18/2560/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/core18/2560/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.2
/snap/core18/2560/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgmp.so
/snap/core18/2566/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/core18/2566/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.2
/snap/core18/2566/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgmp.so
/snap/core20/1611/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/core20/1611/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.0
/snap/core20/1623/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/core20/1623/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.2
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.0
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.4.1
```

Does this mean that I have it installed and can use it? Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question/answer shows how to get the version of GMP: [How to check the version of GMP, MPFR and CamlIDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469182/how-to-check-the-version-of-gmp-mpfr-and-camlidl). It will give an error when GMP is not installed.

Comment: Ignore snap. You have the runtime package, but you are missing the developer package. You should start Ubuntu's package manager and look for gmp in there, that's what the package manager is for.